# SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 60

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have try to install vagrant but I've got this errors i dn't understand why.
Please help

```
SOPHEAKs-MacBook-Pro:Vagrant sopheak$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise64'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise64
==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise64' (v1.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64/versions/1.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 60
SOPHEAKs-MacBook-Pro:Vagrant sopheak$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errno 60 is a socket timeout.  I have also seen this with hashicorp's servers recently.  It will probably clear with a retry.  `vagrant up` will resume the box download, rather than restarting from scratch so this should proceed quickly.